# How to get a number of content scripts loaded on a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I get an amount of content scripts that was loaded into the page by chrome extension if I inject my script in each iframe? Now, I am obtaining a number of content scripts that is loaded to web page by counting a number of iframes + 1.

> +1 because we have one content script that is loaded directly to the page

My manifest.json :

```
"content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

Is is possible at all? 
Thanks!

Comment: Errr, what are you trying to do again? Why do you need to know the number?

Comment: I send a message from background script to content. I need to do something (show some pop up) after all content scripts have executed.

Comment: Interesting. It will be hard to do it by counting though: iframes can be nested.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I did not find any another solution.

Comment: Well, it's possible to do by adding a counter to window.top. For example, when first content script is loaded to a page, I add new variable window.top.contentScriptNumber = 1. And then, when the next one script is loaded to the page, I'll increment my counter - window.top.contentScriptNumber++.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really hacky way to do it.

`chrome.tabs.executeScript`'s callback has a not-often-used argument: the *array* of execution results (last evaluated values). You can inject an empty content script to count the execution contexts:

```
// Requires host permissions to all frames
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: ""}, function(result) {
  console.log("There are " + result.length + " execution contexts");
});
```